# Dynamic button enable knockout js based on error group

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I have a text box and a button. When the text box is empty, I need the button to be disabled and when I start typing in the text box, I want the button to be enabled.

Currently, after inputing some text in the text box, the button is enabled the moment I focus out of the text box. But I want this to be enabled the moment is text box is not empty. I am using knockout.js and both my text box and the button are observables. 
I have nore than 1 text field and I want to enable if all fields are not empty. If any field is empty, without loosing focus, I want to disable the button
Here's my code:

```
var email = ko.observable({ emailField: ko.observable().extend({ email:
true, required: { param: true, message: FILL_FIELD } })), enableButton
 = ko.observable(), errorGroup = ko.validation.group([emailField]);
```

```html
<input type="text" data-bind="value:emailField" />
<button data-bind="enable: enableButton>Press Next to enter password</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

- Use [`textInput`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/textinput-binding.html) for KO 3.2.0 and higher; or
- Use `value` alongside [`valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html#parameters) for lower versions;

Both make sure your view model is updated immediately after key presses, cascading to other bindings like `enable`.

Comment: if I use any of those, the moment I start typing in, the error message keeps displaying. For example : if my field is to take minimum 5 characters, the moment i key in 1 character, it keeps poping the error message.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that complicates your question is that you've got validation going on, and you want the validation to wait until focus exits, so having the values update continuously with your typing is not a solution.

Instead, you could watch `input` events separately, to keep track of which of your required fields are empty. `watchForEmpty` is a factory that takes an observable and returns a Knockout event handler. It sets up the initial state of the list of empties, and the event handler maintains it. The button is enabled when the list of empties has no entries.

```js
vm = {
  empties: ko.observableArray(),
  thing: ko.observable('prefilled'),
  thing2: ko.observable(),
  watchForEmpty: function(observable) {
    var initVal = observable();
    if (initVal === '' || initVal === undefined) {
      vm.empties.push(observable);
    }
    return function(context, event) {
      var el = event.target;
      if (el.value === '') {
        vm.empties.push(observable);
      } else {
        vm.empties.remove(observable);
      }
    };
  }
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input data-bind="value: thing, event: {input: watchForEmpty(thing)}" />
<input data-bind="value: thing2, event: {input: watchForEmpty(thing2)}" />
<button data-bind="enable: empties().length === 0">Go</button>
<div data-bind="text: thing"></div>
<div data-bind="text: thing2"></div>
```